# OpenID Connect with Spring Security 3.x.x

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

I need to implement OpenID Connect with an existing Spring MVC 3.x.x. project.
I have been searching for last 3 days but no luck. There are plenty of examples on internet to implement OpenID Connect with Spring BOOT. But I could not found the steps to do it with Spring security 3.x.x project.

Does anyone know any good reference to achieve the same?? I do not want to start from scratch.

Thanks.

**Update:** I only need to implement Resource server and client part. I have already done a successful POC with **WSO2 as IDP**   and a sample app as Client.

Comment: Hi, did you use MITRid ? I want to use it only for login from SalesForce and want to keep spring security stuff as it is, my app has spring security 3.1.2 and unfortunately I am not in a position to upgrade at this piont.

Comment: Hi, I managed to made it work by adding dependencies of spring-oauth-2 and overwriting some configuration. MITREid is certainly helpfull, but after a POC we decided to go with above approach as it required less changes in existing app. Unfortunately, I do not have that POC code with me now to share with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use MITREid Connect **1.2.x**, that is based on Spring Security **3.2.9**.

Note that the latest MITREid Connect branch is not **1.2.x** but higher (**1.3.x** at the time of this post), and the **1.3.x** is based on Spring Security **4.2.2**.

So you need to specify the 1.2.x subtree to get the "old" **1.2.x** branch on GitHub: https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/tree/1.2.x